# Fixing corrupt encoding (with Python)

Tags: python, encoding

I have bunch of text files contains Korean characters with wrong encodings. Specifically, it seems the characters are encoded with EUC-KR, but the files themselves were saved with UTF8+BOM.

So far I managed to fix a file with the following:

1. Open a file with EditPlus (it shows the file's encoding is `UTF8+BOM`)
2. In EditPlus, save the file as `ANSI`
3. Lastly, in Python:

   ```
   with codecs.open(html, 'rb', encoding='euc-kr') as source_file:
       contents = source_file.read()

   with open(html, 'w+b') as dest_file:
       dest_file.write(contents.encode('utf-8'))
   ```

I want to automate this, but I have not been able to do so. I can open the original file in Python:

```
codecs.open(html, 'rb', encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

However, I haven't been able to figure out how to do the **2.** part.

Comment: Can you show us a sample line from the data file? The first line or so with the BOM would be best.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am presuming here that you have text *already* encoded to EUC-KR, then encoded *again* to UTF-8. If so, encoding to Latin 1 (what Windows calls ANSI) is indeed the best way to get back to the original EUC-KR bytestring.

Open the file as UTF8 with BOM, encode to Latin1, decode as EUC-KR:

```
import io

with io.open(html, encoding='utf-8-sig') as infh:
    data = infh.read().encode('latin1').decode('euc-kr')

with io.open(html, 'w', encoding='utf8') as outfh:
    outfh.write(data)
```

I'm using the [`io.open()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open) here instead of `codecs` as the more robust method; `io` is the new Python 3 library also backported to Python 2.

Demo:

```
>>> broken = '\xef\xbb\xbf\xc2\xb9\xc3\x8c\xc2\xbc\xc3\xba'
>>> print broken.decode('utf-8-sig').encode('latin1').decode('euc-kr')
미술
```

Comment: It turned out I had another set of files with different encodings. Could you pleas take a look at the edited question and see if you can help me out? Thanks!

Comment: It is very hard to say what process produced those other bytes. There is too little context here; not enough info about what text it is *supposed* to represent, or what process these files have gone through. The Unicode character that is problematic there is the Euro symbol, so perhaps a Windows codepage codec would work instead of Latin-1; there are several CP125x codecs that are close to Latin-1 except for such things as the Euro symbol. Make it a new question with a larger excerpt perhaps.

Comment: Please do not mind. I just found that those were generated by myself while trying to fix the original problem long time ago. I recovered the original files, and they can be fixed with your answer. Thanks again.