# Detecting corrupt characters in UTF-8 encoded text file

Tags: regex, encoding, awk, utf-8, scripting

I have a text file that was edited with the wrong character encoding and thus has some mojibake and corrupt characters in some of the strings when I open it using UTF-8. What scripting language would be the most efficient at detecting these corrupt characters? Perl is not an option. I am basically trying to find a way to scan through a text file using a script and output the line numbers and possibly offset where a corrupted character is found. How do I go about this? I was thinking about using AWk, but I don't know what regular expression to use in searching for the corrupted characters. If I could be pointed in the right direction, that would be great.

More Comprehensive Input:

I want the script to tell me the line number that has the corrupted characters which would be the fifth line in the above example. Also, there are different languages in the text file. I have English
Chinese,
French,
Spanish,
Russian,
Portuguese,
Turkish,
French_Euro,
German,
Dutch,
Flemish,
Korean,
Portuguese_Moz. And I have a few special characters also like # and ! and ***

I used this if statement to get the above output:

```
if($1 ~ /[^\x00-\x7F]/){
print NR ":" , $0 > "output.txt";
count++;
}
```

Comment: [some](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20768475/fixing-corrupt-encoding-with-python) pythonic ideas

Comment: Can you edit your question to show sample input and expected output?

Comment: UTF-8 Unicode corruption ? Do a find with `[\x{D800}-\x{DBFF}]|[\x{110000}-\x{7FFFFFFF}]`

Comment: See this unix.se question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6516/filtering-invalid-utf8 . I find an `iconv` solution works well, but there are a few beartraps.

Comment: @EdMorton I added some sample input.

Comment: @sln I used the provided regex in a if statement and it printed out all the lines of text in the file.

Comment: There are _no_ invalid UTF-8 characters in your text. If you are talking about _matching_ chars in the _extended ascii_ range, that would be this `[\x{80}-\x{FF}]`

Comment: When I cut'n paste this `# and !` into my editor I see this binary `0023 0020 0061 006E 0064 0020 0021`, which seems like ascii to me.

Comment: If you are talking about converting language codepoints that's something different.

Comment: You broke the script by changing it. Awk is a series of `<condition> { <action> }` statements. I can't imagine what it made of you adding `if()` around the condition - maybe it thought you had some variable or function named `if`and you were trying string concatenation with the result of a test or... I really have no idea. Just don't do it though - use the script as posted. Also, post the expected output given that input, we can't test a possible solution without knowing what the output should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This finds all chars outside of the ASCII range:

```
$ awk '/[^\x00-\x7F]/{ print NR ":", $0 }' file
1: Interruptor EC nÃ£o estÃ¡ em DESLOCAR
4: è¾…åŠ©é©¾é©¶å®¤é—¨å…³é—­
5: Porte cab. aux. fermÃ©e
7: Ð”Ð²ÐµÑ€ÑŒ Ð°Ð¿Ð¿Ð°Ñ€Ð°Ñ‚Ð½Ð¾Ð¹ ÐºÐ°Ð¼ÐµÑ€Ñ‹ Ð·Ð°ÐºÑ€Ñ‹Ñ‚Ð°
13: é«˜åŽ‹ä¿æŠ¤æ‰‹æŸ„å‘ä¸‹
14: BarriÃ¨re descendue
16: ÐžÐ³Ñ€Ð°Ð½Ð¸Ñ‡. ÐŸÐ»Ð°Ð½ÐºÐ° Ð’Ð’Ðš Ð¾Ð¿ÑƒÑ‰.
19: Barra de separaÃ§Ã£o descida
22: DPæœªå¯åŠ¨
23: Puiss. rÃ©p. non activÃ©e
25: !!! Ð’Ð½ÐµÑˆÐ½ÑÑ Ð¼Ð¾Ñ‰Ð½Ð¾ÑÑ‚ÑŒ Ð½Ðµ Ð²ÐºÐ»ÑŽÑ‡ÐµÐ½Ð°
26: PotÃªncia Dist NÃ£o Ativada
28: PotÃªncia dist nÃ£o activada
31: æœºè½¦æœªç§»åŠ¨
33: Motor no se estÃ¡ moviendo
34: Ð›Ð¾ÐºÐ¾Ð¼Ð¾Ñ‚Ð¸Ð² Ð½ÐµÐ¿Ð¾Ð´Ð²Ð¸Ð¶ÐµÐ½
35: Auto NÃ£o se Movendo
37: A nÃ£o se move
40: æœºè½¦çŠ¶å†µå…è®¸è‡ªåŠ¨åœæœº
41: Conditions auto\npermettent arrÃªt auto
43: Ð£ÑÑ‚Ð°Ð½Ð¾Ð²ÐºÐ¸ Ð»Ð¾ÐºÐ¾Ð¼Ð¾Ñ‚Ð¸Ð²Ð°\nÐŸÑ€ÐµÐ´ÑƒÑÐ¼Ð°Ñ‚Ñ€Ð¸Ð²Ð°ÑŽÑ‚ Ð     °Ð²Ñ‚Ð¾Ð¼Ð°Ñ‚Ð¸Ñ‡ÐµÑÐºÑƒÑŽ Ð¾ÑÑ‚Ð°Ð½Ð¾Ð²ÐºÑƒ
44: CondiÃ§Ãµes da moto\nPermitem Auto Parada
```

Is that good enough? If not please edit your question to show more comprehensive sample input including cases for which the above does not work.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work the way I expected it to. I used it in an if statement like this: `code` if($1 ~ /[^\x00-\x7F]/)
   {
    print NR ":" , $0 > "output.txt";
    count++;
   }`code` and it gave the output above.

Comment: Can't imagine why you'd mess with the script like that. Just don't do that. I've updated my answer to show the script running against your new sample input. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Thank you for your help. The reason i tried putting the awk command in an if statement was because the script has to be automated to run and check multiple files in a folder and not just one manually check one specific file. How would you turn that awk one-liner into an executable script that can check all the files in a specific folder sir?

Comment: Just change the arg from `file` to `*`.