# Detect weird characters in all character fields in a data.frame

Tags: r, character-encoding, data.table

I have a large `data.frame` `d` that was read from a .csv file using read (it is actually a `data.table` resulting from `fread` a .csv file). I want to check in every column of type character for weird/corrupted characters. Meaning the weird sequences of characters that result from other corrupted parts of a text file or from using the wrong encoding.

A `data.table` solution, or some other fast solution, would be best.

This is a pseudo-code for a possible solution

1. create a vector `str_cols` with the names of all the character columns of `d`
2. for each column `j` in `str_cols` compute a frequency table of the values: `tab <-d[,.N,j]`. (this step is probably not necessary, just used to reduce the dimensions of the object that will be checked in columns with repetitions)
3. Check the values of `j` in the summary table `tab`

The crucial step is 3. Is there a function that does that?

Edit1: Perhaps some smart regular expression? [This is a related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738924/detecting-corrupt-characters-in-utf-8-encoded-text-file) non R question, trying to explicitly list all weird characters. Another solution perhaps is to find any character outside of the accepted list of characters `[a-z 0-9 + punctuation]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you post some example data it would be easier to give a more definitive answer. You could likely try something like this though.

```
DT[, lapply(.SD, stringr::str_detect, "^[^[[:print:]]]+$")]
```

It will return a data.table of the same size, but any string that has characters that aren't alphanumeric, punctuation, and/or space will be replaced with TRUE, and everything else replaced with FALSE. This would be my interpretation of your question about wanting to detect values that contain these characters.

You can change the behavior by replacing str_detect with whatever base R or stringr function you want, and slightly modifying the regex as needed. For example, you can remove the offending characters with the following code.

```
DT[, lapply(.SD, stringr::str_replace_all, "[^[[:print:]]]", "")]
```

Comment: This is great.  This caught many problems. It still does not detect this character: "‡" (double dagger or diesis) as a problem character. But I imagine I need to customize the REGEX to my case.

Comment: `[[:print:]]` might be too forgiving, so you might try explicitly specifying alphanumeric, punctuation, and space.The regex.`"^[^[[:alnum:]][[:punct:]]\\s]]+$"`

Comment: tks. It would also be nice to detect character encoding fragments such as when  something like "\00h5" shows up in the text (although they are numbers and letters). Pehaps the key is to make "\" illegal.